# Is there a standard function in C that allows for setting a specific delay in nSec?

Tags: c, timer, avr

In my application I need to generate a function in C that will provide a specific time delay in nano seconds. This delay timer must be done in software as I don't have any hardware timers left in my AVR MCU. My problem is that I would like to be able to set the value in nanoseconds. My MCU clock is 20MHz (50nS period). I thought a quick "for" loop, like;

```
for (n=0; n<value; n++)
```

but that won't take into account how many cycles are added to each time around the loop when compiled. Has anyone got any suggestions? I really don't want to write the code in assembler.

Comment: No, there isn't a standard function which does that. My suggestion is that you rethink the way you use timers. In embedded code I wrote, I would typiclly implement a general clock timer, that can be used for many purposes. Then instead of the dreaded software delay, it is easy to implement a delay function based on that timer's counting.

Comment: I would look for a free-running hardware counter that increments on every clock. Does your MCU have such a counter?

Comment: If your system has a sufficiently complete POSIX implementation, there is the standard POSIX function [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html).  That's a standard function for use in C programs, but it is not part of the ISO/IEC 9899:2018 C standard (or any earlier edition of it).  There's a distinct chance that the function isn't available, or can't be used because you've used all the hardware timers.  In that case, you're likely to be reduced to hand-coded assembler.  Or change the way you use the hardware timers.

Comment: If the hardware can't do it then what makes you assume there's a function for it?

Comment: You could always calibrate the loop. Loop to a billion or something, measure how long it takes with a stopwatch (or a built-in hardware timer), and then work out how many nanoseconds each loop takes.

Comment: you can probably use `timer_settime()`

Comment: Are you thinking of millions of nano seconds or a few nano seconds (e.g. fewer than 100)?

Comment: Could you provide more context/background? Any idea to delay by nanoseconds seems to me like a XY problem solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is certainly not an XY problem.  When you are programming a microcontroller, there are plenty of reasons to delay for a matter of nanoseconds.  For instance, you might be interfacing with a device that has particular timing requirements for the signals that are sent to it, so you need to have control of the timing of your program.  Also, all suggestions to use Linux or POSIX functions are pretty irrelevant; I don't think they are implemented on AVRs.

Answer (score 1):

You give us too few information btw. but I think I can answer without them but it makes answer long. Lets start with easier problem that is you have this situation that your action need to be executed less times than the most frequent isr is executing. For example you need send byte every 1s but your isr is executing every 1ms. So in short you need to send byte every 1000 executions ISR, then you make counter in ISR thats incrementing every ISR and when reaches 1000 you send byte and set cnt to 0.

```
ISR()
{
  cnt++;
  if(cnt >= 1000)
  {
    execute(Z);
    cnt = 0;
  }
}
```

When you have opposed problem, isr is slower than desired time of executing your actions then I stand for redesign your use of timers. You should then make this ISR to execute faster and then divide time by counting exectued isr as I described above. This was mentioned in comments.

> My suggestion is that you rethink the way you use timers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an AVR, you should look into using the AVR-Libc delay functions, `_delay_us` and `_delau_ms`, which are documented here:

https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html

They are standard in the context of AVRs, but not standard for all C environments in general.

Some example code to get you started:

```c
#define F_CPU 20000000
#include <util/delay.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    _delay_us(0.05);
  }
}
```

Note that even though the `_delay_us` and `_delay_ms` functions each take a `double` as an argument, all floating point arithmetic is done at compile time if possible in order to produce efficient code for your delay.